# QScintilla scrollbar

Tags: python, qt, scintilla

When I add a QsciScintilla object to my main window the horizontal scrollbar is active and super wide (tons of apparent white space). Easy fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix:

```
sc.SendScintilla(sc.SCI_SETHSCROLLBAR, 0)
```